# Using signed url for subfolder

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am evaluating google cloud storage for following use case. I need restrict my users (they do not have gmail accounts) so they can access only their files.

I know that can be done using [gsutil signurl](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/signurl). But its gonna be lots of small files and generating signed url for every file is crazy. So wondering if there is trick to provide access to some subfolder using signed url?

Mentioned documentation says that wildcards can be used. Does it mean that it will generate many urls or one url that will apply to all files within wildcard?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [per-object ACL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control) for this, absolutely. Signed URLs might be more difficult to implement, and if you're already thinking of managing user accounts, you'll want to do this through OAuth2.0 for Login anyways, so sending the user's Bearer token with any requests you make to the API should come as a magical bonus of doing your user accounts in this way. Read more about Auth with Cloud Storage [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication).

Comment: As I said in question, I can't assume that users have google accounts or force them to do so.  And documentation says that is possible restrict only google users and google groups. So I don't think I can use OAuth as you suggested.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to generate a signed URL for each file, ACL is the only other ACL solution (hehe) you can hope to implement... well that's not true. You could use RSA to encrypt each file, storing private decryption keys on each users' computer... It's up to you.

Comment: If you'd like to see something implemented on the platform, you should chip in a use-case [feature request in the public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request). Either OpenID ACLs or per-bucket/sub"folder" signed-URLs would give you an option here other than just generating the signed URLs per-object or forcing users to use a Google Account.

Comment: You could always take away ACL for any object in your bucket other than to the service account of your app, and have the users interact with your own app's auth layer before your app retrieves the data for them, if they passed auth and your own defined access-control logic.

Comment: ```
Cloud Storage lets you provide browser-based authenticated downloads to users who have Google accounts but do not necessarily have Cloud Storage accounts.
```

the users need google accounts, what about the others?

Comment: Signed URLs function as their own authentication. If the user has a signed URL, it effectively contains its auth token ("query-string authentication"). [Read up on it in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls).

Answer (score -1):

Unlike the gsutil ls command, the signurl command does not support operations on sub-directories. For example, unless you have an object named **some-directory/** stored inside the bucket **some-bucket**, the following command returns an error: **gsutil signurl  gs://some-bucket/some-directory/**